# Limiting Table.AddFuzzyClusterColumn from Changing Specific Values in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Using Power Query in Excel to clean up data in a column where the entries are similar but not the same.  I've adjusted the threshold to .95 and that's cleaned a lot of it up however, one specific value "FQF" is being changed to another "QFF" where "FQF" and "QFF" are actually two different values.

Is there a known workaround for this?  It's changing it to something similar to what you see below.  "QFF" should remain "QFF" and "FQF" should remain "FQF".  When I look at the threshold value for these it's a "1" (or 100%).

| Original | Fixed Name |
| --- | --- |
| FQF | QFF |
| QFF | QFF |
| FQF | QFF |
| FQF | QFF |
| QFF | QFF |
| FQF | QFF |

Comment: you could always do a replace step on the original before the fuzzy, or use the transformation table option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-fuzzygroup

Comment: Agree with horseyride - use a transformation table for edge cases.